# YAD - Terminal frame

Tags: bash, user-interface, terminal, frame

I'm writing a GUI script with YAD, and I want to show command-line output inside the dialog, Similar to how the Ubuntu installation window has a built-in frame that displays terminal output.

Here's my code so far, it's just a simple dd script

```
sudo echo start

frmdata=$(yad --width=300 --length=300 --title "Make IMG" --text="When this Dialog closes, your image will be created and mounted" --form --field "Name" --field="Size in MB")

frmaddr=$(echo $frmdata | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|" } { print $1 }')
frmname=$(echo $frmdata | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|" } { print $2 }')

dd if=/dev/zero of=$frmaddr.img iflag=fullblock bs=1M count=$frmname && sync

sudo losetup

sudo losetup -d /dev/loop1

sudo losetup loop1 $frmaddr.img
```

And the resulting dialog:
[image]